# D3 force layout create strange line and black rectangle when dragging

Tags: javascript, d3.js, force-layout, drag

I have a force graph with simple nodes and link. Each node is a svg file 500x500.

- I implemented zoom and dragging.
- When clicked on a node, that node
  become fixed while other is released

The problem is there are weird popping line and black shape if I drag a node and then panning around.

I do not know how to put it in words so I record this video. I used Firefox:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2W405T4XZ7ZZDlLRkc0RE01NG8/view?usp=sharing

Edit: I added the json

```
{
  "nodes":[
    {"name":"Mohamed","type":"CEO"},
    {"name":"Google.Inc","type":"Company"},
    {"name":"Apple","type":"Company"},
    {"name":"Leonardo Decaprio","type":"CEO"},
    {"name":"Prisoner A","type":"Prisoner"},
    {"name":"National Bank of Hakuna","type":"Bank"},
    {"name":"Shanghai Major Bank","type":"Bank"},
    {"name":"Boeing 747","type":"Boat"},
    {"name":"Company Ltd.","type":"Company"},
    {"name":"Shanghai Major Bank","type":"Bank"},
    {"name":"Boeing 747","type":"Boat"}
  ],
"links":[
    {"source":0,"target":1,"value":1},
    {"source":1,"target":3,"value":1},
    {"source":2,"target":0,"value":8},
    {"source":3,"target":0,"value":10},
    {"source":3,"target":2,"value":6},
    {"source":3,"target":4,"value":1},
    {"source":5,"target":0,"value":1},
    {"source":6,"target":0,"value":1},
    {"source":7,"target":0,"value":1},
    {"source":8,"target":0,"value":2},
    {"source":3,"target":1,"value":1}
]}
```

Edit: I added the source code as per requested.

```
var force = d3.layout.force()
.charge(-1000)
.linkDistance(80)
.gravity(.05)
.size([width, height]);

 var drag = force.drag()
.origin(function(d) { return d; })
.on("dragstart", dragstarted)
.on("drag", dragged)
.on("dragend", dragended);

var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
    .scaleExtent([0.1, 10])
    .on("zoom", zoomed);




var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .call(zoom);

var container = svg.append("g");

function zoomed() {
  container.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
}
function dragstarted(d) {
   d3.event.sourceEvent.stopPropagation();
   d3.select(this).classed("dragging", true);
}

function dragged(d) {
   d3.select(this).attr("x", d.x = d3.event.x).attr("y", d.y = d3.event.y);
}

function dragended(d) {
   d3.select(this).classed("dragging", false);
}


d3.json("pst.json", function(error, graph) {
  if (error) throw error;

   root=graph.nodes[0];
    root.x = width / 2;
    root.y = height / 2;
    root.fixed = true;


  var link = container.append("g").selectAll(".link")
      .data(graph.links)
    .enter().append("line")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .style("stroke-width", function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.value); });

  var node = container.append("g").selectAll(".node")
      .data(graph.nodes)
      .enter()
      .append("image")
      .attr("xlink:href",function(d){return d.type+ ".svg" ;})
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return d.x+12; })
      .attr("y", function(d) { return d.y+12; })
      .attr("width", "24px")
      .attr("height", "24px")
      .call(force.drag)
      .on("click",click);

  force
      .nodes(graph.nodes)
      .links(graph.links)
      .start(); 

  node.append("title")
      .text(function(d) { return d.name; });

  function click(node) {
   root.fixed = false;
   root=node;
   root.fixed=true;

}

  force.on("tick", function() {
    link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
        .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

    node.attr("x", function(d) { return d.x-12; })
     .attr("y", function(d) { return d.y-12; });   
  });
});
```

Comment: Could you provide source code? Or a fiddle...

Comment: @Khelmo : I added the source code for viewing

Comment: Could you provide a small data sample from the json? Also css, if u have any

Comment: What browser is giving you trouble?  I tried [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/F28FVnaRa8KUQsBhHmmb?p=preview) to reproduce it in both Chrome and IE11 but was unsuccessful.

Comment: @Mark: I was using Firefox. The exact version I will reply when I can get to the laptop. But after testing, I found out that I can do any kind of zoom and the problem will not show again. But refresh and without zooming, the phantom bug shows up again :(